# Serializable Dynamic Objects created in C# ( WCF ) not accessible in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, dynamicobject

In my solution I have the webservice (backend) written in C# and served via WCF to the client which is the MVC3 web front-end with VB.NET. For one web service I need to send to the client a list of dynamic objects  `List<SerializableDynamicObject>`.

I implemented solution described here: [WCF Serializaiont of DLR](http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/) , [Example code](http://www.ninjarobotarmy.com/ninjarobotarmy/dynsrv/dynsrv.zip).
In my test console application written in C# I can easily read dynamic properties served by WCF. Unfortunately in the VB.NET console application when I try to call one of the property I receive error message for first property "Public member 'TRIP_ID' on type 'SerializableDynamicObject' not found". The interesting thing is that I can see in the "Watch" and "Locals" windows dynamic properties for served objects in both C# and VB.NET.

Can anyone explain to me what is the problem and how to solve this ?  Thanks...

The webservice code:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{        
    public object Process(object value)
    {
        dynamic d = new SerializableDynamicObject();
        d.TRIP_ID = Convert.ToInt64(1);
        d.TRIP_NAM = "TRIP NAM";
        d.TRIP_USR_CRE_DTE = DateTime.Now;
        d.TripValue = new SerializableDynamicObject();
        d.TripValue.TPVL_TRIP_ID = Convert.ToInt64(1);
        d.TripValue.TPVL_VAL = "TPVL VAL";
        return d;
    }

}
```

The C# version to read WCF dynamic objects (works), the dynamic properties are visible and can be called:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = new SerializableDynamicObject();
        d.Testing = "this is a test.";
        DynService.Service1Client client = new DynService.Service1Client();
        dynamic res = client.Process(d);
        Int64  TRIP_ID = res.TRIP_ID; 
        string TRIP_NAM = res.TRIP_NAM;
        DateTime TRIP_USR_CRE_DTE = res.TRIP_USR_CRE_DTE;
        Int64 TPVL_TRIP_ID = res.TripValue.TPVL_TRIP_ID;
        string TPVL_VAL = res.TripValue.TPVL_VAL;             
    }
}
```

The VB.NET version to read WCF dynamic objects (not working)

```
Option Strict Off
Option Infer On
Imports System.Linq
Imports DynSrv
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim d As Object = New SerializableDynamicObject()
        d.Testing = "this is a test."
        Dim client As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()
        Dim res As Object = client.Process(d)
        Dim TRIP_ID As Int64 = res.TRIP_ID
        Dim TRIP_NAM As String = res.TRIP_NAM
        Dim TRIP_USR_CRE_DTE As Date = res.TRIP_USR_CRE_DTE
        Dim TPVL_TRIP_ID As Int64 = res.TripValue.TPVL_TRIP_ID
        Dim TPVL_VAL As String = res.TripValue.TPVL_VAL

    End Sub
End Module
```